# R Dataframes : Arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data of 11784 records split into test (2946) and train (8838) to run a h20 algorithm, but got an error related to the data frame that I'm trying to create as the final output to link the predictions and the ids that the predictions were made for.

Error for this line: 
df_y_test <- data.frame(ID = df_labels, Status = df_y_test$predict)

**Error in data.frame(ID = df_labels, Status = df_y_test$predict) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2946, 2950**

Looked through the forums and understood that the number of rows in df_y_test is 2950 which is causing this, but couldn't figure out why since df_y_test is also derived from the same 'test' variable overall which has only 2946 rows - would be happy for any guidance please, full script posted below for reference

data : 11784 obs of 46 variables 
test: 2946 obs of 45 variables 
train: 8838 obs of 46 variables 
df_labels: 2946 obs of 1 variable 
df_y_test: 2950 obs of 4 variables

```
# Load Data
data <- read.csv('Data.csv')

# Partition Data 
library(caTools)
set.seed(75)
split <- sample.split(data$Status, SplitRatio = 0.75)
train <- subset(data, split == TRUE)
test <- subset(data, split == FALSE)

# Dropping the column to be predicted from Test 
test <- subset(test[,-c(2)])

library(readr)
library(h2o)

# Init h2o
localh2o <- h2o.init(max_mem_size = '2g', nthreads = -1)

# convert status values (to be predicted) in second column to factors in h2o
train[,2] <- as.factor(train[,2])
train_h2o <- as.h2o(train)
test_h2o <- as.h2o(test)

# Running H2O
model <- h2o.deeplearning(x=c(1, 3:46), 
                       y=2,
                       training_frame = train_h2o,
                       activation = "RectifierWithDropout", 
                       input_dropout_ratio = 0.2,
                       hidden_dropout_ratios = c(0.5, 0.5),
                       balance_classes = TRUE,
                       hidden = c(100,100),
                       nesterov_accelerated_gradient = T,
                       epochs = 15 ) 

h2o_y_test <- h2o.predict(model, test_h2o)

# Converting to data frames from h2o
df_y_test <- as.data.frame(h2o_y_test)
df_labels <- as.data.frame(test[,1])
df_y_test <- data.frame(ID = df_labels, Status = df_y_test$predict)

write.csv(df_y_test, file="predictionsH2o.csv", row.names = FALSE)

h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing the data, but as a guess, are there any missing values in your data and is your code removing missing values (perhaps implicitly) in one place but not in another? As an example (that doesn't appear to apply to your data, but is just for illustration using the built-in `mtcars` data frame): `mtcars$wt[5] = NA; m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars); data.frame(mtcars$wt, predict(m1))`.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 -  tried from scratch with the NA removals and it worked now.